# Displaying overflow in footer field on a new page

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have a TextBox in the footer of my report that takes a column that can store up to 5000 characters, but the TextBox in the footer can't take 5000 characters due to its size. In my tests, the TextBox has displayed a number of chars between 1000 ('M' letters) and 1800 (dots).

I'd like a new page to be created if this field overflows, and I want the overflown part to be displayed in the footer of following pages, thus giving the column the proper space, divided in two or more pages.

**Summarizing: Rather than displaying the beginning of my oversized field in my footer textbox every other page, I want the whole content of the field to be diplayed in the footer of several pages.**

**Note:** Defining a number of characters to be displayed in the first page, and displaying the rest in other pages is not an option, because we cannot come anywhere near precision when it comes to characters and length using fixed numbers because each character has a different length.

**Note2:** Is more information required? I'll describe it thoroughly if you ask! Leave a comment

Comment: Have you considered changing the font in the footer to a fixed width font so you can fix the number of characters to use?

Comment: @RC_Cleland This report actually follows a Brazilan standard for a document of transportation of goods, and it has a set of supported typefaces :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDI will get you part of the way. You can use GDI's MeasureString to measure a string given a particular font. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx)

Armed with the knowledge of how big your footer area is, a custom WillStringFitInMyFooter function and a thousand bruises from your reporting tool I think you can solve this.

Comment: There's a problem with this logic. Even if I get that it's going to need to go to a new page, I won't know where to make the cut, because I can't know where the length reaches the limit of the first page anyway, unless there's some way of finding out the lenth of the string through SSRS. Another thing: Isn't there a way to do this entirely in SSRS ? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about SSRS. Maybe someone else will know.

I was thinking something more like this:
public string GetTheOverflow(string fullString, Font fontToUse, SizeF sizeOfBox)
{
  // Loop (or b-tree through) asking "will fit?" on substrings until it is done or returns no. Everything beyond this point is overflow.
}

Comment: Oh, this makes sense.. but I'd still need to handle it outside of SSRS, the kind of solution I'm looking for is preferably a change in the report solution.. but thanks! that's given me some ideas

Comment: Although the issue has been solved through other ways, I've accepted this answer, as it was very useful.